# Python Cassandra Driver Only Inserts One Record

Tags: python, cassandra

Trying to get this insert to work and only a single record gets inserted despite not seeing any errors.  It works normally if I spell out the fields, but doing it with the JSON literal is much easier.

Doing this in a loop from stdin:

```
batch = BatchStatement(consistency_level=ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM)
stmt = cassy_session.prepare("INSERT INTO social_objects JSON ?;")
batch.add(stmt, (json.dumps(so_record),))
stmt = cassy_session.prepare("INSERT INTO social_users JSON ?;")
batch.add(stmt, (json.dumps(user_record),))
cassy_session.execute(batch)
```

Also tried this:

```
cassy_session.execute(stmt, [json.dumps(user_record)])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're seeing [CASSANDRA-10631](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10631), which affects prepared `INSERT JSON` statements.  This should be fixed in Cassandra 2.2.4.

Comment: That does appear to be the issue.  It effects 3.0.0 as well.